# Displaying values from two tables in java

Tags: java, jdbc

I  created a connection with a data base with Java and I would like to display data from two tables.

In the query statement I used a JOIN command but i am struggling with a syntax error.
Was hoping for some advice in regards to this.

```
try
    {
        Class.forName(driverName);
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(SourceURL, user, password);


        Statement listDisplay = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet displayAll = listDisplay.executeQuery("SELECT AnimalType.typeID, AnimalType.description, Animal.name "
                                                     +"FROM Animal "
                                                     +"JOIN AnimalType "       
                                                     +"ON AnimalType.typeID = Animal.typeIDForeign");  
        while(displayAll.next())
        {
            int typeId = displayAll.getInt(1);
            String description = displayAll.getString(2);
            String name = displayAll.getString(3);

            System.out.println(typeId + " " + description + " " + name);
        }

        connection.close();

        }
        catch(SQLException sql)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sql.toString());
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException exe)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, exe.toString());
        }
```

Will it work what I am trying to do here.?

regards
Arian

Comment: Since you could reproduce the same error in a command line app. with no GUI, this has *nothing* to do with Swing.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. Made a slight alteration with query and now its fine...thanks. ("SELECT AnimalType.typeID, AnimalType.description, Animal.name" + "FROM AnimalType, Animal " +"WHERE AnimalType.typeID = Animal.typeIDForeign");

Comment: Can you delete the question, or at least amend it to show the proper query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally do it somewhat like this:

```
if (displayAll.first())
{
    do
    {
        int typeId = displayAll.getInt(1);
        String description = displayAll.getString(2);
        String name = displayAll.getString(3);

        System.out.println(typeId + " " + description + " " + name);
    } while(displayAll.next());
}
displayAll.close();
listDisplay.close();
```